# Angular Momentum Conservation vs Kepler's law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, orbital-motion

Let a planetary system be solely consisted of the earth and the sun with the earth revolving around the sun in a perfectly circular orbit. If the radial distance (R) of the earth from the sun is doubled, what will be the new revolving time (T)?
If I apply Kepler's law of $T^2$ proportional to $R^3$ that yields T=1032 days. However, if I apply the conservation law of angular momentum:

Mass(m)$\times$angular speed(w)$\times$$R^2$= Constant,

or $w$$\times$$R^2$=constant,
or (2$\times$$\frac \pi T$)$\times$$R^2$=constant,
or $R^2$=constant$\times$T,
or T proportional to $R^2$; that is different from the Kepler's law!
Can you please tell me in which assumption I am making the mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Angular momentum is conserved between two points *on the same trajectory*.  In other words, the angular momentum of the Earth about the sun is the same right now as it was three hours ago.

This does *not* mean that the angular momentum of the Earth would be the same no matter how large its orbit is.

Comment: Quite right.  The conservation of angular momentum implies Kepler's 2nd law, the one that says that a planet (on a given trajectory!) sweeps out equal areas in equal times.

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of angular momentum applies to isolated systems. You cannot change the radius of circular orbit in your scenario, and retain the masses, without outside influence.

Comment: dear, you have said that trajectory must be the same to apply the conservation law! However, in case of a rope revolving over the head with one side attached to a mass, how to calculate the revolving time if the person handling the rope suddenly doubles the rope?

Answer (score 0):

In the Kepler Law $T^2 =kR^3$. When you increase the radius the constant does not change. K will have the same value i.e $ \frac{4\pi ^2}{GM} $ when you change the radius as it has no dependence on R.

The first equation you use is Angular momentum(MVR) = constant.
And The last equation that you put up is $R^2$ = constant $\times$ T.
When you increase the radius the angular momentum increases according to the first equation. And the constant changes. That means in the last equation as you change R to 2R, the constant value also changes and that means you'll have to take that under consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you cannot assume a conservation of angular momentum when you double the orbital radius of earth. Keplers 3rd Law (for circular orbits) $$T_1^2:T_2^2=R_1^3:R_2^2 \tag1$$ follows from equating the centripetal force on earth with the gravitational force $$F_c=mR\omega^2=G\frac {m·M}{4\pi R^2}\tag 2$$ from which follow $$\omega^2·R^3=(\frac {2\pi}{T})^2·R^3=G\frac {M}{4\pi}=const \tag 3$$ which corresponds to Keplers's Law (1). The angular momentum of earth is given by $$L=m\omega R^2$$ Thus with eq. (3) this gives $$(\frac {L}{m})^2=const·R$$ This shows that the angular momentum of earth is proportional to the square root of the orbital radius $R$. When you double the orbital radius of earth, the angular momentum will not be constant but it will increase by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have used conservation of momentum to get angular velocity, the time that u got there was the time for the planet to rotate and not revolve but the time u get when u use Keplers law of planetary motion is the time of revolution and not rotation hence the time periods are different.